# Reporting closure of NRI/NRE/NRO bank account when filing US federal income tax

Tags: united-states, income-tax, banking, bank-account, foreign-income

I am aware that if my foreign account holds a balance exceeding $10K I have to report it in FBAR when filing income tax. This became a hassle, so I closed it in mid-2014, and reported the account and whatever interest income I earned on it before its closure, when I filed in 2015 (for the year ending 12/31/2014).

My question is: since I haven't had any foreign bank account during the whole of 2015, can I simply not report anything when filing this year (2016)? Do I have to somehow report that it was closed and that's why I am not reporting it? I have all the necessary documentation from the SBI NRI branch that shows it was closed. Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 1):

Just don't list it any more. No special reporting needed. Check if there's a checkbox for "account was closed this year" somewhere, I vaguely remember there used to be.

Comment: Thanks, this checkbox you are referring to is in which form? Do you remember that? Is that form 1040, or FBAR, or something else? It can't be FBAR I guess, otherwise it means I need to file FBAR.

Comment: I remember seeing it on form 8938, but I don't think its there now. Not sure if I made it up or they removed it. in any case, you only report accounts you have during the year, obviously.